# ArrayAdapter not showing added elements in ListView, Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, listview, android-listview

I recently added a SearchView element to my menu in my app, which filter correctly the elements in my ListView. The problem comes after i search something, in fact, if i try to add an element to my ListView, it doesn't show the element.
The element added actually goes inside the ArrayList in my code, i checked it through Debugging Tools. Any ideas?

This is the OnQueryTextListener for my SearchView:

```
 searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) { 
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) { 
            adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

I think the problem is the ArrayAdapter. If you need further details, i can post them here.

Edit #1

ArrayAdapter:

```
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Contatto>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, r.arr);
    rubrica.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Add Element method:

```
    public void Aggiungi(View view){

    String n,c,t;

    n = editNome.getText().toString();

    c = editCognome.getText().toString();

    t = editNumero.getText().toString();

    if(!PhoneNumberUtils.isGlobalPhoneNumber("+39" +  t) || (t.length() < 8) ){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Inserisci un numero internazionale valido.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

    r.aggiungiContatto(n , c , t); //C'è qualcosa che non va nel filtrare i tutto.
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

r is the object that contains the ArrayList. The "aggiungiContatto" method is:

```
public void aggiungiContatto(String nome, String cognome, String numeroCell){
    Contatto c=new Contatto(nome, cognome, numeroCell);
    arr.add(c);
}
```

Should be enough.

Comment: Can you share your adapter code and the part where your adding new item to ListView

Comment: @ShobhithYadav sure.

Comment: Try change `arr.add(c);` to `adapter.add(c);`.

Comment: @i_A_mok just tried, doing so the element  doesn't even get inside the ArrayList.

Comment: After filtering the ArrayAdapter, did you try notifying about the changes using adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: @Nikhil Bansal tried also that, and didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below may be a work around, try:

```
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
            adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
            if (s.equals("")) {
                adapter = new ArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, r.arr);
                rubrica.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
            return true;
        }
```